# Redirect from http to https in Node.js and Express.js using Windows

Tags: node.js, ssl, express

I've seen [this topic about the same issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22332442/redirect-http-to-https-express-js) but the provided solutions don't seem to change the port from 3000 to the default 443 used with SSL.

I've seen in some places `iptables` should be used to accomplish it, but in a windows environment this can not be done that way.

Temporarily I've fixed it by manually removing the 3000 port by myself:

```
//redirecting to HTTPS if the connection is not secure
app.use(function(req,resp,next){
    if (!req.secure) {
        return resp.redirect(301, 'https://' + req.headers.host.replace(':3000', '') +  req.url);
    } else {
        return next();
    }
});
```

Any proper solution for it?

Comment: Do you access your node app "directly"? Don't you proxy it from for example IIS? http://dvisagie.blogspot.it/2013/02/running-nodejs-alongside-iis-on-windows.html Then it will be more easy redirect 80 to 443

Comment: @Michelem I have access to the node app yep. And I'm not using IIS.

Comment: Did you try this? https://gist.github.com/youtalk/3216781 But I still prefer the IIS proxy solution

Comment: @Michelem that doesn't remove the port from the URL. Which will keep the `:3000`