# HTTPS webpage - NodeJS

Tags: node.js

I have four pages inside a folder "public". I want to open that pages with HTTPS beacause getusermedia() no longer works in HTTP connections. This is my code:

```
var express = require("express");
var https = require('https');
var BinaryServer = require('binaryjs').BinaryServer;
var fs = require('fs');
var options = {
  key: fs.readFileSync('key.pem'),
  cert: fs.readFileSync('cert.pem')
};
var app = express();
var server = https.createServer(options, app);//.listen(9000);
app.use(express.static('public'));
app.listen(9000);
```

But the pages doesn't open in HTTPS (just open in HTTP). Before I check the certificate I want to be sure that everything is ok with the code.

Comment: What error you got while open in browser?

Comment: May I know what you mean by none?. Does the console throw any error? Browser throw any certificate missing error? in Mozilla/Chrome they will show warning.

Comment: @Sathish No, the console don't throw any error.

Comment: Since you are listening on port 9000 I assume you are behind a reverse proxy (i.e. Apache or nginx)? If this is the case the proxy should handle the (force) SSL, not your express app.

Comment: Are you specifying the port?  For example, https: //www.example.com:9000/

Comment: No I am not behind of a reverse proxy. But know I understand what you mean. The NodeJS itself doens't handle the SSL. Right?

Comment: Yes. I am @Gary Doing `my.IP/8000:page.html`

Comment: node can handle SSL (it's a pain though). The interesting question is how your production setup looks like as it will probably involve a reverse proxy which might be the best option for handling SSL. If this is not an option you need to do it on node level.

Comment: @carduh Your code says port 9000, you said 8000.  Also, format is https : // ip :9000/page.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You shouldnt use app.listen, as this is still only the "regular" express app (aka http) I believe.

This should point you in the right direction (taken from the API docs @ http://expressjs.com/en/api.html)

Edit:

Added in how your code should look:

```
var express = require("express");
var https = require('https');
var BinaryServer = require('binaryjs').BinaryServer;
var fs = require('fs');
var options = {
  key: fs.readFileSync('key.pem'),
  cert: fs.readFileSync('cert.pem')
};
var app = express();
app.use(express.static('public'));

https.createServer(options, app).listen(9000);
```

Comment: Thats the answer... And other mistake I made is the call of the link.. I forget to write the https part (it seems necessary). The result is: `https://_ip:_port/_my_web_page.html`

Comment: Correct. The easiest thing to do there is just to have http redirect to https (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22332442/redirect-http-to-https-express-js has a solution to redirect http to https)