# Redirect HTTP traffic to HTTPS in Gatsby

Tags: reactjs, gatsby

I would like to redirect HTTP traffic to HTTPS as this is a Lighthouse requirement for PWAs. My site is built with Gatsby.

I found various plugins like the ones below which seem to imply that the answer comes from modifying the `.htaccess` file.

https://www.gatsbyjs.org/packages/gatsby-plugin-htaccess/

For the plugin above, I tried the following configuration, which didn't pass the PWA audit:

```
{
      resolve: 'gatsby-plugin-htaccess',
      options: {
        RewriteBase: '/custom/',
        https: true,
        www: true,
        SymLinksIfOwnerMatch: true,
        host: 'av-site.com',
        redirect: [
          'RewriteRule ^not-existing-url/?$ /existing-url [R=301,L,NE]',
          {
            from: 'http:av-site.com',
            to: 'https:av-site.com',
          },
        ],
      },
    },
```

Can anyone please help me? Thanks!

Comment: This isn't something you want to be doing in JavaScript, React, or Gatsby. You should use [HTTP redirects](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Redirections) implemented in your application backend (e.g. [express.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22332442/redirect-http-to-https-express-js)), host (e.g. [Netlify](https://docs.netlify.com/routing/redirects/)), or server (e.g. [nginx](https://serversforhackers.com/c/redirect-http-to-https-nginx)). Also consider using [HSTS](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Strict-Transport-Security).

Comment: Thanks for your reply! In the end, I went with Nick C's answer below as it leverages Gatsby's native functionality for this (through gatsby-config.js).

Comment: Right, and that's what I'm advising against. Redirecting client-side isn't secure or performant. Gatsby doesn't have a server-side runtime—you have to configure your host or server appropriately.

Comment: I see. I'll try out the server-side redirect approach then. I deploy on Netlify so I'll look into leveraging that. Thanks for the info!

Comment: It's super easy on Netlify by enabling HSTS. https://docs.netlify.com/domains-https/https-ssl/#hsts-preload

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Make sure in `gatsby-config.js` the `siteURL` is https

```
module.exports = {
  siteMetadata: {
    title: `example`,
    description: ``,
    author: `me`,
    siteUrl: `https://example.com`
  },
```

Comment: That's it! Thanks!

Comment: Glad I could help!

Comment: Any suggestions if this doesn't do the trick? Works on one site, fails on another.

Comment: I ended up recreating the `CNAME` entry on Cloudflare, and despite it being identical, that's what fixed it. Very aggravating; I hope this helps someone.

Comment: Glad you could resolve your issue. Often when using services like cloudfair etc.  They will require you to “recreate” the environmental credentials inside their console. Or at least park them there.