# How to redirect http to https in Gatsby?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, gatsby

I need to redirect all traffic from http to https in my gatsby site. I did the same as in this answer (set the siteUrl and also used this plugin to redirect) [Redirect HTTP traffic to HTTPS in Gatsby](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57044036/redirect-http-traffic-to-https-in-gatsby) and it still doesn't work. What can I do if this solution doesn't make my site redirect to https?

Comment: My advice is out of the scope of Gatsby, but I recommend you to host your NS records on Cloudflare (it's free) and make any kind of redirections with the rules from there. Less of a hassle, more secure & cleaner than waiting for any kind of framework to do the redirection.

Comment: @Mimoid — This isn't related to JavaScript, Node, React, or Gatsby. It's specifically about [HTTP redirects](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Redirections) and how to implement one using your backend (e.g. [express.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22332442/redirect-http-to-https-express-js)), host (e.g. [Netlify](https://docs.netlify.com/routing/redirects/)), or server (e.g. [nginx](https://serversforhackers.com/c/redirect-http-to-https-nginx)).

Comment: @HiroyukiNuri Thanks, I used cloudflare and it works now how I wanted